# How do I maintain Promise context between TypeScript classes?

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I have a TypeScript class with a class method that returns a promise:

```
GetSampleTrackingData() {
    return new Promise<TrackingData>((resolve) => {
        fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'sim1.txt'), (err, data) => {
            //Irrelevant code removed
            resolve(foo);
        });
    });
}
```

When it's called, it throws the error `ReferenceError: fs is not defined`. The code worked fine when not wrapped in the promise.

Essentially, the context is not being maintained when the promise is called. (it's being called from Express.js)

If it's relevant, I've tried a few different ways to import 'fs'.

How can I make the promise maintain the context?

[Link to the class in GitHub](https://github.com/ytechie/SimpleTrackingV3/blob/master/src/providers/sim/SimTracker.ts)

Comment: Simply putting `new Promise()` around the code would not cause `fs` to become undefined. Are you sure that the error is coming from that line?

Comment: Great question! I just tried checking 'fs' on the previous line, and it is indeed defined.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: There's no other info in the error object. I'm starting to think this is a TypeScript thing. Simply using the 'fs' object outside that block changes the code that TypeScript generates. It basically removes the reference. I'm in contact with the TypeScript team to troubleshoot.

Comment: For future reference, why are people downvotting this? It's a real issue (that I'm now going to enter an answer for - turns out it's a bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the TypeScript team, and it turns out this is a TypeScript bug that occurs in 2.7.1. The fix should be in 2.7.2.

When you use the `tsc -w` option, it is incorrectly removing some references when the code is used within a promise. The fix is to downgrade to 2.6, or use `tsc` without the `-w` option.

[Here is the bug they pointed me to.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21612)